# servlet and jsp sending query result following MVC framework

Tags: hibernate, jsp, servlets

in order to separate java code and html code and be more faithful to MVC framework i am  coding like that;

in the servlet i put the following:

```
net.sf.hibernate.Session s = null;
    net.sf.hibernate.Transaction tx;
    try {

        s= HibernateUtil.currentSession();
        tx=s.beginTransaction();
        Query query = s.createQuery("select  opcemployees.Nom,opcemployees.Prenom,dailytimesheet.TrackingDate,dailytimesheet.Activity," +
                "dailytimesheet.ProjectCode,dailytimesheet.WAName,dailytimesheet.TaskCode," +
                "dailytimesheet.TimeSpent,dailytimesheet.PercentTaskComplete from  Opcemployees opcemployees,Dailytimesheet dailytimesheet  " +
                "where opcemployees.Matricule=dailytimesheet.Matricule  and dailytimesheet.Etat=3 " +
                "group by opcemployees.Nom,opcemployees.Prenom" );  


             for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();)
             {                                                                           
                               if(it.hasNext()){

                                   Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();
                                   request.setAttribute("items", row);
                               }}
                               } catch (HibernateException e){ 


                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

request.getRequestDispatcher("EspaceValidation.jsp").forward(request, response);

and in jsp i start like that:

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
    <tr>
        <td>? </td>
        <td>?</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

in this case what should i put exactly to obtain my result.a table fulled with the right value from the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Hibernate but not taking benefit of all its capabilities, I suggest to get yourself through a basic Hibernate tutorial first. The Tutorial as described in [Hibernate Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/) is good to get started.

Regardless, you need to create a model object which represents one entity of the `Opcemployees` table (I would rather rename it to `Opcemployee`, but that's another story) and also another one which represents one entity of the `Dailytimesheet` table.

```
public class Opcemployee {
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private Dailytimesheet dailytimesheet;

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    // Add/generate remnant of constructors, getters and setters.
}

public class Dailytimesheet {
    private Date trackingDate;
    private String activity; // Not sure if this is supposed to be String.
    private String projectCode;
    // ...

    // Add/generate constructors, getters and setters.
}
```

Those objects should have `private` properties and `public` getters and setters. Most IDE's like Netbeans, Eclipse and IntelliJ can autogenerate them for you. There exist even the [HibernateTools](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.0.0.CR1/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html) plugin which can do this all almost automatically with a few clicks based on an existing database model.

If everything is properly done and configured, you should end up with querying the data in the Servlet like this:

```
List<Opcemployee> opcemployees = session.createQuery("from Opcemployees").list();
```

Now you've a `List` of model objects which is useable in JSP. You need to let the Servlet store this list in the request scope and forward the request to the JSP.

```
request.setAttribute("opcemployees", opcemployees);
request.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

This way it's accessible by `${opcemployees}` in `page.jsp`.

```
<p>All employees: ${opcemployees}</p>
```

But this is not nicely formatted. It's the outcome of [`List#toString()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29). As if you're doing a `System.out.println(opcemployees)` in Servlet. You need to iterate over it using JSTL [`c:forEach`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) tag (just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib` to install it):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<c:forEach items="${opcemployees}" var="opcemployee">
    <p>${opcemployee}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

This does the same as the following in normal Java code:

```
for (Opcemployee opcemployee : opcemployees) {
    System.out.println(opcemployee);
}
```

This is getting somewhat better. Every item is printed separately. But we want to have every property of an item in a separate table cell. So we need to write a HTML table around it and print a new `<tr>` on every iteration and access all properties separately inside a `<td>`.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${opcemployees}" var="opcemployee">
        <tr>
            <td>${opcemployee.nom}</td>
            <td>${opcemployee.prenom}</td>
            <td>${opcemployee.dailytimesheet.trackingDate}</td>
            <td>${opcemployee.dailytimesheet.activity}</td>
            <td>${opcemployee.dailytimesheet.projectCode}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

The `${opcemployee.nom}` basically does a `System.out.println(opcemployee.getNom())`. As you see, you can chain getter methods in EL. The `${opcemployee.dailytimesheet.projectcode}` will print the result of `opcemployee.getDailytimesheet().getProjectCode()`.

Hope this helps. Also see this [JSP/Servlet tutorial](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html). The same site also ships with excellent kickoff [Hibernate tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/hibernate.html).